# Can't open new single section

Tags: routes, sections, singles

I created a new Single section and named it "test", added some content and tried to view it on `domain.com/test`. Unfortunately I get my default server 404 and not the new single section.

I tried to add a new route using `"test" => "_layout"` but can't see any change.

Do you have any idea why this isn't working?

**EDIT:**

Here the both screenshots.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtgBB.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JomkJ.jpg

I hope that helps.

Comment: Could you share screenshots of your section settings and entry type settings for your "test" single section?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a template called test.html that extends the "_layout.html" template. The layout template is just a wrapper template, and with the "_" in front of it, it will always be invisible to a browser.

Take a look at the twig references on extending templates. Also look at the templates supplied with the initial install to get a better idea how this works.

[Twig Extend](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html)

Routes are for more refined routing of templates and you should not need a route for current implementation.

Imagine if "_layout.html" were named "_wrapper.html" and it makes a little more sense.